# Display Json data in laravel

Tags: json, laravel

How can I get and display each element from the product json data type in laravel.

```
"category" => accessories 
"product" => "["eyewear", "watches", "shoes"]"
```

Data has been saved correctly using

```
 $casts = [
    'product' => 'array'
];
```

When I try to display, I get the list like show down
Category :
accessories  |      Product  :      ["eyewear", "watches", "shoes"]

Is it possible to get result like
Category :   accessories  |   Product:  eyewear *****
Category :   accessories  |   Product:  watches *****
Category :   accessories  |   Product:  shoes   *****

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Provided the JSON has indeed been successfully converted to an array (in this case to a 1D array), you can get the value for each index like you normally would with any other array:

```
{{ $product[0] }}
```

If you want to create some sort of list out of it, you can just loop through it using foreach:

```
@foreach($product as $p)
    {{ "Category: " . $category }}
    {{ "Product: " . $p }}
@endforeach
```

If I understand correctly you already have some query results stored in `$items`, where you have stored values for `category_id` and `product` (based on your original post I assume you've already converted the JSON to an array using the [$casts](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) property inside your model, alternatively you could use PHP function [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)). If you want to loop through `$items`, it would probably look like this:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    @foreach($item['product'] as $product)
        {{ "Category: ".$item['category_id']." | Product: ".$product }}
        </br>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The code above should output something like this:

```
Category: 1 | Product: eyewear
Category: 1 | Product: watches
Category: 1 | Product: shoes
Category: 2 | Product: a
Category: 2 | Product: b
Category: 2 | Product: c
```

Comment: Getting data from database, How can I convert to array and display, really I'm new in laravel. To display I use foreach like below :                                                                            @foreach($product as $prod)
    {{$items->category_id }}
    {{$items->product }}
@endforeach                                                                                                                    I want to display each category for each product in the list.

Comment: I just edited the answer. Hope I understand what you're trying to do correctly.

Comment: Also, if I may say so, I don't think you should use JSON in your database unless you absolutely have to. It would much easier to work with if you had a separate `products` table referencing the category using a foreign key.

Comment: Indeed I have 2 tables category and product. I register a list of product in json by category. Category(category_id) is foreign key in the product table. I didn't want to save single product for category each time, too much product to save that why I use json, If another solution please let me know.   "how can I add code easily here in order to show my controller and route?". Mistake in my previous code sorry                                                  ***@foreach($product as $prod) {{$prod->category_id }} {{$prod->product }} @endforeach)***Every data come from product table

Comment: You can post the code if you edit your original post or post it as an answer if that's what you're asking. Also, it would generally be better to make every product into its very own record in the database. It's more efficient that way, almost no extra work thanks to Laravel and also makes it easier to expand the database in the future should it be needed.